# Alternative name support in moshi for converting to json

Tags: android, json, moshi

I have members in Json format, which are named different when serializing and deserializing. Do moshi have any concept like alternate provided in gson..

FromJson: I get:
{
name:"Ted"
}

ToJson
{
firstname:"Ted"
}

In moshi, can this be solved by one model class with single adapter or by using annotation ?

Comment: I'd use different models to model the different data you want to encode vs. decode.

Answer (score 3):

There's nothing like this in Moshi and the mainteners don't think it's a fit for the library, but this issue might point you to a workaround: https://github.com/square/moshi/issues/303.